# is there any length function for the Django Model Objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, loops

I've hard coded this 3 in my loop range because I was unable to get the actual length. I tried listing the available features but didn't found any print(dir(Todo_Item.objects)).
Maybe is there any other better way to iterate over the object and stop when it ends?
This is my code with hard coded 3 in loop range.

```
def home_view(request):
display_list = []
for i in range(3):
    display_list.append(Todo_Item.objects.get(id=i+1).task)
.......some code below as well.......
```

My Todo app runs fine without any error but the only problem is this non-dynamic loop.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need anything filtration, you can do that:

```
todo_items = Todo_Item.objects.all()
for item in todo_items:
    print(item.task)
```

also you can iterate over it into your template:

```
{% for item in todo_items %}
        <li>{{ item.task }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Preliminary add `todo_items` into render context.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little rusty with Django, but I think what you want is to fetch all of the Todo_Items in one go and iterate over them. For that, you would want to use the [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) method to fetch an entire QuerySet. With that, you can iterate over each item it returns:

```
def home_view(request):
    display_list = []
    todo_items = Todo_Item.objects.all()
    for item in todo_items:
        display_list.append(item.task)
    .......some code below as well.......
```

Again, I am pretty out of practice using Django, but I think there is also a way to fetch the `task` value for each item you select all in one go, but I cannot remember exactly how. Django has a powerful query syntax, so check out these pages to learn more:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/